# Displaying raw jsx code on my webpage. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am working on a client page in reactjs with socket.io and express. i have a basic file called login.jsx and trying to display the web code that is at the end of the file in a return block. but it is displaying the raw code.

[Screenshot of issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53EoH.png)

I am using the sendFile function under express for this as shown here.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('Login.jsx', { root: "../frontend/src/pages" });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: In simple words, JSX is being "rendered". This means, that it's compiled. Hence, by sending whole file via response, you won't be able to send compiled JSX code, but whole file. 

I understand that you want to return HTML code that is rendered. To do so, you must first compile JSX code. 

Are using SSR?

Comment: I have compiled the code.

Comment: If you have done so, then you should return your raw html code using refs. Wrap your code, set the ref and then return the ref's current through the response.